# Meaning of following code

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, if-statement

I have a sample app which i downloaded from net
In this i was unable to understand following code

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (localNotif == nil) 
    return;
```

also

```
  if (!array1) 
        return;
```

does this code means if object does not exists  then return.....

HELP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cocoa, an initialiser will either return an object pointer if the call was successful, or a nil if it was unable to create the object.

Both cases are checking for the existence of the object. Actually, checking for the existence of a pointer to the object and simply returning if the object does not exist. As an example, here is a common form of initialiser for an object.

```
- (id)init  {
    // Call the superclass initialiser first and check that it was successful.
    if (!(self = [super init])) {
        // If the superclass initialiser failed then self will be nil.
        // return a nil because we cannot create this object.
        return nil; // Bail!
    }
    // Do more initialising 
    // If we can initialise the superclass and ourself, return a pointer to ourself
    return self;
}
```

However, the snippets you have provided are not enough to tell whether the code is correct. For example, the first example is incorrect if it is part of an initialiser method because it is not returning any kind of object.

**Edit**

From your further examples both of these print hiiiiiiii

```
NSArray *arr;
if(arr) { NSLog(@"hiiiiii");
```

and

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]init];
if(arr) { NSLog(@"hiiiiii");
```

In the first case you are declaring arr to be a pointer to an NSArray, but because it hasn't been initialised this pointer is just a garbage value of random numbers. But it isn't `nil` So your if-statement    evaluates as true. That doesn't mean that it is a valid pointer to an NSArray.

In your second example you declare an NSArray pointer and initialise it. This was successfully initialised so the pointer is not nil and the if-statement evaluates as true. In this case you do have a valid NSArray pointer.

Declaration is not initialisation!

Maybe if you explain what it is that you are trying to do we'll be able to better answer your questions.

Comment: @Abizern---I have made comments to Ishu Gupta and  willcodejavaforfood please check them what is wrong there....

Comment: @online. Done. You are confusing declaration with initialisation.

Comment: @Abizern--Might be but i know well about declaration with initialisation......in both my sample examples(Given in comments to ishu gupta)...are producing same output ...But you said if object was allocated then only the condition will true....

Comment: @Abizern---I am waiting sir....for your answer.....Why output is there.......are both if conditions checking for different things........actually your words...."You are confusing declaration with initialisation"...more confused me...

Answer (score 2):

They are both checking if the object is nil. In the first case it seems a bit silly though :)

Comment: object is nil means...it does not has any value..?

Comment: @Online - uninitialized, undefined, empty, or meaningless value

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood--Following to your answer i did following in both cases output is same why?

NSArray *arr;  
 
 if(arr)
 {
  NSLog(@"hiiiiii"); 
 }    
.........................and............  
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]init];

 
 if(arr)
 {    
  NSLog(@"hiiiiii"); 
 }

Comment: @online. When you say `NSArray *arr` then `arr` has a garbage value. It is not really a pointer to an array, just a random pointer that hasn't been initialised. Try `NSInteger number = [arr count];` in your first example and it will generate an error, or a crash. Declaring a pointer is not the same thing as initialising a pointer

Comment: That's because the garbage value for the first pointer is not a nil. All you are doing in both cases is checking against a nil, not whether both are valid NSArray pointers.

Comment: @willcodeforjava,what is the work of alloc.and when object is nil.

Comment: @willcodeforjava--sorry for again and again but will you please tell me how to check whether an object is valid  pointer

Answer (score -1):

Yes, except in the first case localNotif will not be nil because it has been set

Comment: Not true. If the initialisation of the UILocalNotification failed the init method will return nil. The standard Cocoa paradigm for init calls is to return an object pointer, or a nil on failure, so in the first case, the object will not have been set if there was an error.

Comment: Still no point checking.  In the same way you dont check for nil if you allocate cocoa objects, eg.  NSString *str = [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"string"];